# Converting C++ maps to Java map

Tags: java, c++, c++11, java-8, java-stream

consider the following cpp code

```cpp
string ans = "NO";
map<int,vi> idv ; //vi is vector of int

for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
  idv.[arr[i]].push_back(i);

//frequecy >= 3
for(auto el:idv){
   if(el.ss.size() >= 3){
      ans = "YES";}
}

//non adjecent equal elements
for(auto el:idv)
{
   if(el.ss.size() == 2 && el.ss[0] != el.ss[1]-1)
    {
      ans = "YES";
    }
}

cout<<ans<<endl;
```

> My java translation code

```java
                String ans = "NO";
                Map<Integer,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
                for (int i : arr) {
                    // map.merge(i,1,Integer::sum);
                    // map.put(i, )
                    List<Integer> temp = map.getOrDefault(i, new ArrayList<>());
                    temp.add(i);
                    map.put(i,temp);

                }

                //check for freq 3
                for (Map.Entry<Integer,List<Integer>> e : map.entrySet()) 
                {
                    if(e.getValue().size() == 3)     
                        ans ="YES";
                }

                //freq 2 and pos change 
                for (Map.Entry<Integer,List<Integer>> i : map.entrySet()) 
                {
                    if(i.getValue().size() == 2 && i.getValue().get(0) != i.getValue().get(1) - 1)
                        ans = "YES";    
                }

                System.out.println(ans);
```

> Input arr[]

```
1 2 1
1 2 2 3 2
1 1 2
1 2 2 1
1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5
```

> Output

```
YES
YES
NO
YES
NO
```

But Its not working properly as intended. Please can anyone tell me how to do it more efficiently. Also for the in first loop I think I could use map.merge. If anyone knows how to do it please let me know .
Thanks ✌️

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: If any one of the  criteria is Matched then answer will be yes else no

Comment: Please, provide sample input and output. This is not clear.

Comment: You need a better example - nothing I do will get "idv.[arr[i]].push_back(i);" to compile. It's not C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the following snippet pushes the indices to end of the vector and you need to approach the same in Java without enhanced for-each loop:

```
// C++
for (int i=1;i<=n;i++)
    idv.[arr[i]].push_back(i);

// Java
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    List<Integer> temp = map.getOrDefault(arr[i], new ArrayList<>());
    temp.add(i);
    map.put(arr[i],temp);

    // or shorter:
    // map.computeIfAbsent(arr[i], key->new ArrayList<>()).add(i);
}
```

The next thing is you iterate in both Java and C++ the map twice which is not necessary. Use the same logical disjunction. In Java, you can iterate values only, no need to iterate through actual entries if you don't need keys:

```
for (List<Integer> list: map.values()) {
    if (list.size() == 3 || (list.size() == 2 && list.get(0) != list.get(1) - 1)) {
        ans = "YES";
        break;        // no need to continue iteration, you have the answer
    }
}
```

The whole thing can be even more simplified using the advantage of [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) helping you to create the `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>>  map1 = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> arr[i]));

String ans = "NO";
for (List<Integer> list: map.values()){
    if (list.size() == 3 || (list.size() == 2 && list.get(0) != list.get(1) - 1)) {
        ans = "YES";
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks to @[Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger), this can be even simpler using `Collectors.collectingAndThen`:

```
String ans = IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.groupingBy(i -> arr[i]),
        map -> map.values().stream()
            .filter(l -> l.size() == 3 || (l.size() == 2 && l.get(0) != l.get(1) - 1))
            .findAny().map(x -> "YES").orElse("NO")));
```

Comment: Instead of `getOrDefault(arr[i], new ArrayList<>())`, followed by a redundant `map.put(arr[i],temp)`, you can use a single `computeIfAbsent(arr[i], key->new ArrayList<>())`. This allows the entire operation to be expressed in a single statement: `for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) map.computeIfAbsent(arr[i], key->new ArrayList<>()).add(i);`. For the stream alternative, it would be consistent to use a stream for the second operation as well: `String ans= map.values().stream().filter(list -> list.size()==3 || (list.size()==2 && list.get(0)!=list.get(1)-1).findAny().map(x -> "YES").orElse("NO");`

Comment: Or `String ans= map.values().stream().anyMatch(list -> list.size()==3 || (list.size()==2 && list.get(0)!=list.get(1)-1)? "YES": "NO";`

Comment: That's true. First of all, I wanted to point on the errors. I complete the answer if you don't mind.

Comment: Also @Holger map.values().stream() will do the same using java 8 streams